# If I passed array name as a string to a JS function, then how to loop through it inside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, object

I have a large array of objects.
I want to make an advanced search function that I call it like this:

```
var x = searcArray('students.id=5','history.date=2015/10/10',and more args);
```

Then the function will loop through **students** array and search for **id**=5
then loop through **history** inside that **student** and search for **date**=2015/10/10

then return that array or object

So how can I do it with **JavaScript** or **JQuery**?

Comment: Why would you not  just pass `5` and date string. Note that you could eval it in your case but doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: because it is not always student.id or history.date

Comment: So pass as parameter relevant objects and specific property you want to get, e.g: `searcArray({obj: students, prop: 'id', match: 5}, {obj: history, prop: 'date', match: '2015/10/10'},...);`  Anyway, it sounds like a XY problem. Without seeing why would you need that, hard to tell you what should you use...

Comment: Thanks. your code will help me get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla js you can use [Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [Array Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
but exists a lot of libraries for collections as [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#where)

Comment: wow, I visited there documentation page and it has a great methods.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of keyword `arguments` which basically is an array and it holds all the args passed in the function:

```js
function searcArray(){
  var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(item){
    return item.split('=')[1]
  })
  document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(arr) + '</pre>';
}
searcArray('students.id=5', 'history.date=2015/10/10');
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried like this, check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qe3g001h/)

```
window.students = {'id':5};
window.history = {'date':'2015/10/10'};
function searcArray(){
    var arr = arguments;
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var searchQuery = arr[i].split("=")[0];
        var searchTarget = arr[i].split("=")[1];
        var searchQueryArray = searchQuery.split(".")[0];
        var searchQueryIndex= searchQuery.split(".")[1];
        if(window[searchQueryArray][searchQueryIndex] == searchTarget){
            results.push(1);
        }else{
            results.push(0);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
var x = searcArray('students.id=5','history.date=2015/10/10');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: if it is helpful, please make it as answer